# Change label text using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, label

I want the labels to change whenever the user changes from Metric to Imperial.

It correctly detects the change and stores the current value selected, steps into the if statement, but then nothing happens.

Here is my JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{   
    $("select[name = unit]").change(function()
    {
        var selected = $("option:selected", this).text();

        if(selected == "Metric (cm)")
        {
            $("label[for = unit]").text("mm");
        }
        else if(selected == "Imperial (inches)")
        {
            $("label[for = unit]").text("in");  
        }
    });
})
```

And my html.

```
    <form name ="Calculator">

        Unit of Measurement: 

        <select name = "unit">

            <option value = "120904000">
                Metric (cm)
            </option>

            <option value = "4760000">
                Imperial (inches)
            </option>

        </select>

        <br>


        Root Diameter: <input type = "text" name = "root" autocomplete = "off">
        <label for = "unit"></label>
        <br>

        Width between bearings: <input type = "text" name = "bearings" autocomplete = "off">
        <label for = "unit"></label>
        <br>

        End Fixity: 
        <select name = "fixity">

            <option value = ".36">
            1
            </option>

            <option value = "1.0">
            2
            </option>

            <option value = "1.47">
            3
            </option>

            <option value = "2.23">
            4
            </option>

        </select>

        <br>

        Max Speed (RPM): <input type = "text" name = "speed" autocomplete = "off"><br>

        <a href = "#" class = "reset" onclick = "">Reset</a>
        <a href = "#" class = "calculate" onclick = "checkOp(); return(false);">Calculate</a>
        <a href = "#" class = "close" onclick = "">Exit</a>

    </form>
```

Comment: Post the HTML as well, there's some pretty specific string matching going on there.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't really have an attribute that says  `for = unit` with all that whitespace ?

Comment: When I run this, it looks like changing the selected item does change the label's text. do you want it to display the value + the text in the label? like 120904000mm? or 4760000in?

Comment: I just want it to display "mm" or "in" depending on which unit of measurement the user has chosen.

Comment: then your code looks good to me. maybe edit your question with your entire html and javascript instead of the snippets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cant really guess where u missing.But check this js fiddle where i used your code and its working absolutely fine for me .

[**Your code Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5DnBu/1/)

```
$("select[name = unit]").change(function()
    {
        var selected = $("option:selected", this).text().trim();

        if(selected == "Metric (cm)")
        {
            $("label[for = unit]").text("mm");
        }
        else if(selected == "Imperial (inches)")
        {
            $("label[for = unit]").text("inches");  
        }   });
```

I updated the jsfiddle for you .You needed to add this trim at the end like this :

```
var selected = $("option:selected", this).text().trim();
```

and you set to go.

Here is updated jsfiddle :

[**updated code fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5DnBu/2/)

Comment: Its taking some extra white spacing and your matching selector was getting failed.So you needed to trim that extra white space and then do compare it for selection.

Comment: @user3546428 , Hello if trim is not used then If user enters Blank Space ,then Blank space will be processed .Do u want blank space?